# How is it possible to run the doc-command in a CounterClockwise-REPL in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

Is it somehow possible to start the documentation within the REPL in Eclipse (I'm using the CounterClockwise-Plugin). I tried e.g.

```
(clojure.repl/doc doc)
```

but this throws:

```
ClassNotFoundException clojure.repl  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

When I start a REPL from the terminal (e.g. using `clojure` or `lein repl`), this works fine. I already used the full-qualified name, so I really don't get why this is not working.

Comment: Using the fully qualified name does not ensure the namespace has been loaded, and is often a sign of something that will break (you are relying on the fact that some other code already ensured the namespace would be loaded, and that may not be true later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clojure.repl` namespace comes with Clojure, but is not always in scope.

To get equivalent behavior to a normal repl you can execute the following:

```
 (use 'clojure.repl)
```

Or, more consertatively:

```
 (require '[clojure.repl :as repl])
```